# Not allowing me call python flask API while server still executing some function

Tags: python, flask, python-requests

I am trying to implement flask client server architecture for the first time.

My server code:

```
from flask import Flask, request
from Flask.Config import Config

global config

class MyFlaskApp(Flask):
    def run(self, host=None, port=None, debug=None, load_dotenv=True, **options):
        if not self.debug or os.getenv('WERKZEUG_RUN_MAIN') == 'true':
            with self.app_context():
                init()
        super(MyFlaskApp, self).run(host=host, port=port, debug=debug, load_dotenv=load_dotenv, **options)


app = MyFlaskApp(__name__)


def init():
    global config
    config = Config()
    config.configure()
    config.execute()


@app.route('/get_results/', methods=['POST'])
def process_request():
    global config
    dict = config.get_dictionary()
    json_object = json.dumps(dict)
    return json_object


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run(debug=True, port=5000)
```

I am performing some continuous executions (`while True:` loop) in `config.execute()` method in `init()` function., which updates some dictionary continuously. Client code calls the server API and gets updated dictionary. My client code:

```
import requests    

def main():
    response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:5000/get_parking_results/").json()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

I run server first, it does the intended computations and updates dictionary. But when I run client side code it gives me following error:

```
requests.exceptions.ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='127.0.0.1', port=5000): Max retries exceeded with url: /get_parking_results/ (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x0000020A922D4828>: Failed to establish a new connection: [WinError 10061] No connection could be made because the target machine actively refused it',))
```

However, If I comment `config.execute()` from `init()` function then it successfully returns the dictionary to client. Basically it is not allowing me to send request to server while server is continuously executing something in while loop. Why is this happening? I tried running `init()` function through a separate thread, it worked. What if I don't want to use thread? What is the solution?

Answer (score 1):

Your code executes `run() -> init() -> config.execute() -> while True: ...` before it can start the actual server with `super().run()`.

You want your server process to do two things at the same time: `config.execute()` and running the server so it can handle requests. The only way to do that is with multiple threads or processes.

Multiple processes won't work easily here since you want to share the global `config` object in memory, so threads are best to start with.

This is actually quite easy:

```
import threading

# Under init(), instead of config.execute()
threading.Thread(target=config.execute).start()
```

The alternative without threads is to not try and do multiple things at the same time. Maybe instead of having a `while True` loop, `process_request` can do a little bit of updating to `config` before returning it.

Or you could split your architecture into completely separate processes. One process continuously updates `config` and stores the result in a database or JSON file, while the server reads the file instead of having a global `config` variable.